# the versions 2 of Zend Framework, CodeIgniter, Symfony and CakePHP

Tags: php, frameworks

The most famous php frameworks ([Zend Framework](http://devzone.zend.com/article/12385), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/news/codeigniter_2.0.0_released/), [Symfony](http://symfony-reloaded.org/), and [CakePHP](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/markstory/2010/12/26/happy_holiday_yule_cake_-_cakephp_2_0-dev_released)) were all version 1 for a long time and are all at the same time releasing their versions 2 now, although beta, alpha, pre, dev king of thing. What framework would you choose for a new application this time? Why?

Answer (score 1):

cakephp2, because its what i know. pretty much the same answer anyone with sense would give you. unless you have a serious issue with a framework chances are you will continue to use it.

Comment: +1 Though that would be more suited as a comment ;)